# Ubuntu 18.04 with no monitor attached - no framebuffer device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, framebuffer

I have an [Intel Compute Stick](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/boardsandkits/computestick/STK2m3W64CC_STK2mv64CC_STK2m364CC_TechProdSpec.pdf) with integrated Intel HD Graphics 515 video running Ubuntu 18.04 server (kernel 4.15.0-29-generic) without X windows. For remote access to this system I use TeamViewer, which apparently requires a framebuffer device (/dev/fbX) to run correctly. When I am booting the system with a monitor attached, framebuffer device is present and all is good. When I boot it without a monitor attached, there's no framebuffer device and TeamViewer cannot be used.

Before I  upgraded to Ubutun 18.04, I was using Ubuntu 16.04 (4.4.0-116-generic) and it worked perfectly, with or without monitor.

One more piece of information which might help - after booting without a monitor, connecting a monitor when the system is already up is not detected and the monitor is useless (nothing is displayed). I must reboot in order to use the display

I am looking for a way to force the creation of the framebuffer device upon boot

Answer (score 0):

you may want to have a look at this answer, the problem appears very similar to me, even though in this case the remote access tool was VNC, the underlying characteristics (works with 16.04, does not work with 18.04) appears identical:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066721/headless-server-no-monitor-no-graphics

Comment: Thanks, this solution requires X windows, which I want to avoid.